# How does zoo() fill n rows while the original Dataframe has n-1 row?

Tags: r, time-series, zoo

```
library(dplyr)
```

I have a dataframe with 114 rows :

```
df = data.frame(a= (seq(from = as.Date("2016-11-27"), to = as.Date("2019-01-27"), by = 7)), b=seq(0:5)) #Create a dataframe
colnames(df) <- c("time","value") # change col names
```

Here however we will remove the 4 first rows of the dataframe

```
neodf <- (slice(df, 5:nrow(df)))
colnames(neodf) <- c("time","value") # change col names
```

We create a zoo time series with the same sequence as the original dataframe but with the values of the new dataframe

```
ts <- zoo(neodf$value, seq(from = as.Date("2016-11-27"), to = as.Date("2019-01-27"), by = 7))
```

We can see that the zoo object has indeed more rows than neodf so I was wondering if the zoo object automatically shift values and create values at the end or viceversa ?

My original problem is with some sales timeseries. The original dataframe has 4 observations every month, but in one year at December we only have 1 observation. As you can imagine, since I'm using a zoo() object for the transformation (by using the sequence option) I end up with 4 observations in December and they actually contain values !

Thanks !

Comment: as far as I know it start repeating the values you provided in `x`, e.g. if `x= c(1, 2, 3, 4)` and the `ts` is defined to have 6 values, then you'll get `1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2`

Comment: @DS_UNI thanks, yeah you are right

Comment: Note that this works: `zooreg(neodf$value, start = as.Date("2016-11-27"), deltat = 7)` to create a zooreg object.